# Change chunk_vendors/app js file import urls in public index.html in a Django/Vue application

Tags: django, vue.js, static-files

I want to serve my chunk vendors or app js files under *static/js/chunk_vendors.js* rather than */js/chunk_vendors.js* because I want to point to the dist directory generated for production build by **npm run build** and my static url in Django is */static* so every static file should be access via a url starting with */static*. But npm run build generates an html file with *chunk_vendors.js* url */js/chunk_vendors.js*. How can I tell Vue Cli to generate html files with */static* prefix?

Here is my vue.config.js file : (I need some config parameter like *chunk_url* to indicate a prefix to the chunk files)

```
module.exports={
  pages: {
    'index' : {
      'entry' : './src/pages/home/main.js',
      'template ' : 'public/index.html',
      'title' : 'Home',
      'chunks' : ['chunk-vendors','chunk-common', 'index']
    },
    'memory' : {
      'entry' : './src/pages/memory/main.js',
      'template ' : 'public/index.html',
      'title' : 'Memory',
      'chunks' : ['chunk-vendors','chunk-common', 'memory']
    }
  },
  devServer: {
    disableHostCheck: true
  }
}
```

I checked the reference for Vue configuration but couldn't find any option to define a prefix to chunks.

Answer (score 0):

you can change the default output directory with [outputdir](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#outputdir)

Comment: I'm not trying to change default output directory. I'm trying to change the src link of chunk_vendors to start with prefix /static no matter the file is stored.