# Best Practice to run Django/Vue application on Production

Tags: django, vue.js, production

I have a Django/Vue app and when I am developing, I run two different servers, one for Django on port 8082 and one for Vue with *yarn serve* on port 8080. I want to deploy this application to AWS. I created dist files with *npm run build* and I configured Django to access templates in this dist directory and in my *views.py* I routed to this static html files generated by build process. Is it a good practice to run Django/Vue apps on production or should I be running two different servers for production as well?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great if you could give more detail about your application.

Django template which need to be served by django app, usually you will have additional JavaScript, CSS, images files using by djagno template, which need to be served by web server, so you will have a web server in front of the django app. such as [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04)

The vue parts(only in development it runing like a application), once it is built, it is just static HTML + JavaScript + CSS, which can be served on any web server, also can be served by your web server for django app.

If you want to combine django template together with vuejs, then you need somehing to load built webpack(vue cli is just a webpack wrapper) into template such as [django-webpack-loader](https://github.com/django-webpack/django-webpack-loader), this [article](https://medium.com/js-dojo/vue-django-best-of-both-frontends-701307871478) maybe helpful.

Comment: I went with django-webpack-loader and didn't quite like it actually. I like developing vue app separately from django and I liked the idea to have static files build for production and serve them by web server. But for now, I'd like to serve them within django application (I'll just publish a demo to AWS). The question is, do I have to serve these static files through a web server like nginx rather than the web server running the django application itself in a real production setting?

Comment: Also, if you have any idea about this question it would be great to hear : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69418153/change-chunk-vendors-app-js-file-import-urls-in-public-index-html-in-a-django-vu

Comment: Django dev server can also serving static files(for accessing from not only local, you may need bind the address to 0.0.0.0), so it is can be used for demo/dev purpose.